# update-command-not-found Not Working

Tags: debian, command-not-found

So I am running Debian Testing, and I installed the `command-not-found` package, because I just love that functionality in Ubuntu. So I installed it, and when I restarted my terminal, it said I needed to update the cache for the available packages. So I did. I tried the following commands:

```
sudo update-command-not-found
sudo /usr/sbin/command-not-found
su and update-command-not-found
su and /usr/sbin/update-command-not-found
```

But it just exits and does nothing. No output. Just nothing. I try it and it says I need to update the cache again.

Answer (score 13):

Try a `sudo apt update` or similar first, even if it should be up to date.

Helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install command-not-found
sudo apt update
sudo update-command-not-found
```

Then **you also need to start a new bash session** (or run `source ~/.bashrc`, or log out and back in again, or open a new terminal or ssh connection)